# Multi-Column Text in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview, uitextview, multiple-columns

I'm trying to display some **horizontally** scrolling text in **multiple columns**. The twist is, the column width is known, but the **column count depends on the text length**.

There is an [Core Text Objective-C Wrapper](http://akosma.com/2010/07/08/core-text-objective-c-wrapper/), but it works with a fixed column count which disqualifies it.

I know it would be possible with a `UIWebView` and some CSS 3 using `column-width`, like [shown in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wojtiku/bFKpa/). But I also read that `UIWebView`s obviously need a lot of memory which I want to avoid.

Is there another way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/how-to-create-a-simple-magazine-app-with-core-text) for my own projects, and near the final explains all you want!

Comment: Thank you **a lot** for this link! This is perfect.